# Fiberglass or reflective roll insulation for duct work?

Tags: insulation, ducts

I have some exposed duct work in my garage.  I am looking to insulate it and was looking at the types of insulation.  Is is better to use fiberglass or "bubble wrap" reflective roll insulation? I live in western Pennsylvania.

Comment: You'll really want to provide more details (ex. where are you/warm or cold climate), but odds are, fiberglass if you're trying to stop conduction/convection, and reflective if you want to stop radiative heat loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer bubble wrap as it generally looks nicer and is easier to clean if looks are important. However the R value for single ply with no air gap is generally about R-4. To achieve R-6 you would need to provide an air gap by first cutting strips and then go over the strips with the bubble wrap. R-6 is generally considered the minimum. 2” faced fiberglass is generally R-6 as well.